# Overriding the instance next function

Tags: python

I'm trying to override an object's next function using the code below (python 2.7).

When the object's `next` method is called directly, the new function is invoked. However when I call the builtin `next()` function on my object (which, [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), should call the instance's next method), the ORIGINAL function is invoked.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
class Test(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return 1

test = Test()
def new_next(self):
    return 2

test.next = type(test.__class__.next)(new_next, test, test.__class__)
print test.next() # 2
print next(test) # 1
```

Comment: Interesting. Might be related to [PEP 3114](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114)?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo looks like that PEP is for Python 3

Comment: @warvariuc Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm reading [this source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1dadde8651e7a35189b3e05cbb10625abd8d255/Objects/typeobject.c#L4818) correctly it seems like the iterator is set when the class is defined. I might read it wrong though. I'm guessing it's for fast lookup of the `next` function (setting it as a [slot](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next)) since it's used in loops etc.

Given that, the following seems to do what you're after:

```
>>> test.__class__.next = type(test.__class__.next)(new_next, test, test.__class__)
>>> next(test)
2
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up with a different approach, when I dynamically create a class that inherits from Test, and override the next method there. This way I'm not changing the original class.

Comment: Sounds safer somehow, instead of relying on some undocumented behavior and some guy half-guessing on SO :) Very interesting though, thanks for posting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490998/why-typex-enter-x-instead-of-x-enter-in-python-standard-context/34491119#34491119
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup